# Get the view of a Fragment outside of OnCreateView() - View is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, view, fragment-oncreateview

Inside onCreateView i can instance View with the inflate, in this way:

> ```
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
>                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>
>         // Inflate the layout for this fragment
>         if(savedInstanceState == null) {
>             v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_team, container, false);
>             setUpRecyclerView(v);
>         }
>
>         return v;
>     }
> ```

Now, if launch a second activity when return in the first activity, in this fragment, the View is null  because onCreateView it's already called.
I don't know a to instance the view.

Is there a solution of that?

Comment: apart from the answer already given,I would suggest you instantiate your views in `onViewCreated()` method instead of `onCreateView()`

Comment: Can i write the inflate inside onViewCreated() rather than onCreateView()?
Like this:
v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_team, container, false);

But in onViewCreated() i didn't have the ViewGroup container, how can find it?

Comment: No, onCreateView() is intended to inflate your views, as the name suggests, but if you're worried how to get the view reference that was inflated in onCreateView (), then onViewCreated() also has a view parameter that you can use to do findViewById() on your layout views.

Comment: @AmanGrover can you explain with the code please?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `if(savedInstanceState == null)` validation and create & return your view every time `onCreateView` is invoked.

Comment: The problem is that onCreateView is not invoked second time and the View is not instanceded.

Outside onCreateView is there a way to instanced ViewGroup container? How?

Comment: Fragment will not call onCreateView if it does not need to do so, i.e. if it already has a view provided by onCreateView. Use `getView()` if you need to access the previously created View.